# SCC apply to all services and not only to specific service

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, security-context

when I apply my `custom-scc` on my **Openshift** cluster my service which has the right `serviceAccount : My-service-name` will retrieve it correctly.

However if a pod in another service comes to restart with `default` as `serviceAccount` it will also get my **custom-scc**.

i checked my scc and i added only :

```
users:
- system:serviceaccount:dev:my-service-name-serviceaccount
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Who is starting the other pods?

Clearly this user has permission to use the SCC, else it wouldn't.  So, the question is where are those permissions coming from.

Presumably you've already checked the SCC (including a copy of it here would allow multiple eyes to double check it).  The other main place to look is a clusterrole that permits "USE" to that SCC.  Perhaps you have a clusterrole with "*" that's being applied to the default SA?

Final thought - if you duplicate the new SCC on a fresh cluster install, do you continue to see the issue?  If so, the issue is probably in your SCC.  If not, the issue is probably in another RBAC component in the running system.

Comment: i checked the clusterRole and i didn't see any thing who look like * as value .

Comment: i going to check again all the clusterRole and the default serviceAccount . I cant duplicate the new SCC on a fresh cluster unfortunatelly :( .

Comment: i've compare my SCC  with the default one and the only difference is allowPrivililegeEscalation: false  by default is true

Comment: If the *ONLY* difference is allowPrivilegeEscalation between yours and "restricted", then yours will also have the group permissions for system:authenticated enabled.  So, any logged in user will be able to use it.